# How to show multiple custom markers on barchart without tap on that?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have created a stacked barchart using MPAndroidChart. For the purpose of Marker I have created Custom Markerview. I need markers on the all the slices which have value greater than 0 without tap on barchart and the total value of that slice should be display in marker. How can i do this?